# Prevent setState trigger in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have:

```js
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    outside: false,
    inside: false,
  }
  
  onOutsideClick = () => this.setState({ outside: true })
  
  onInsideClick = () => this.setState({ inside: true })

  render() {
    return (<div onClick={this.onOutsideClick}>Some text, <p onClick={this.onInsideClick}>some other text</p></div>)
  }
}
```

When I click on <kbd>some other text</kbd>, the `onOutsideClick` handler will trigger as well and as such `this.state.outside` will change to true. If <kbd>some other text</kbd> is clicked, I don't want to trigger any other method.

I tried with `e.stopPropagation` and `if (this.state.inside) return` in `onOutsideClick` but none of those worked

Answer (score 1):

You should use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop bubbling event. It's hard to say why `stopPropagation()` hasn't worked for you.

Working demo with `stopPropagation()`: https://codesandbox.io/s/wpPJ1LkXR

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const INSIDE_CLICK = 'inside';
const OUTSIDE_CLICK = 'outside';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    clicked: undefined,
  };

  onOutsideClick = () => {
    this.setState({ clicked: OUTSIDE_CLICK });
  };

  onInsideClick = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.setState({ clicked: INSIDE_CLICK });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onOutsideClick}>
        Some text, <p onClick={this.onInsideClick}>some other text</p>
        <div style={{ border: '2px solid red' }}>
          Clicked: {this.state.clicked}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check some boolean before calling setState and put it to false again in the setState callback.